# Read images from the image paths in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have one column of image paths in pandas DataFrame. It consists of 989 000 rows.

For example:

```
data['ImagesPaths'] = {'path1', 'path2', etc...}
```

And I want to apply `cv2.read()` to this column to have column of Image Arrays

How do you suggest to do it for fast results?

Comment: faster than what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just want to iterate over data['ImagesPaths'] column which can be done pretty easy:

```
for image_path in data['ImagesPaths']:
    image = cv2.read(image_path)
    # do smth.
```

I think speed of image_path retrieval is not a question here, most of the time would be spent on image reading and processing.